# Smooth page change in collaboration with greensock

Tags: animation

How does this site change between pages this smooth?

http://hellomonday.com/

When you go in to a project it's animating in to the new page. If we look at the html, the projects html is not pressent before we animate to it.

I am pretty sure there are using greensock for the animation, but how can you load the new html. Animate to it and then get rid of the main page html that smooth?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are using `GSAP` for animation.

**Content loading & page navigation:**
They are loading all content `(site-content.php)` by a XHR request at the beginning & changing the content in time of page navigation. That’s why the page transition is so smooth.